# org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce Not Found-- Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am working on Hadoop. I need to process images using the power of Big Data. To play around with it, I have referred this [example](http://eldadlevy.wordpress.com/2011/02/05/hadoop-binary-files-processing-entroduced-by-image-duplicates-finder/).
I need to create Sequence file prior working on the image duplicates.
So i used [this](http://pastebin.com/m1EuBaqj) source code for creating sequence file.

When i compile this in Hadoop environment i am missing some packages. I am using Hadoop-0.18.0.

```
/tmp/BinaryFilesToHadoopSequenceFile.java:12: package org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce does not exist
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
                                  ^
/tmp/BinaryFilesToHadoopSequenceFile.java:13: package org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce does not exist
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
                                  ^
/tmp/BinaryFilesToHadoopSequenceFile.java:14: package org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input does not exist
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
                                            ^
/tmp/BinaryFilesToHadoopSequenceFile.java:15: package org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input does not exist
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
                                            ^
/tmp/BinaryFilesToHadoopSequenceFile.java:16: package org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output does not exist
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
                                             ^
/tmp/BinaryFilesToHadoopSequenceFile.java:17: package org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output does not exist
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.SequenceFileOutputFormat;
```

Whether am i doing anything wrong?? Or is it not available in 0.18.0.
I know this version is very old version. Due to some restrictions i am using an already configured VM to work with ,which is having this version of hadoop.
Any Help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't easily find a copy of 0.18.0 to download anymore, but it looks like the mapreduce package was not available in this version (or 0.19):

- http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/h/Downloadhadoop0180corejar.htm
- http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/h/Downloadhadoop0190corejar.htm

It's definately in 0.20.2 though

Comment: Mr White, From the day one i started searching regarding Hadoop i found your name everywhere in this stackoverflow,on every Hadoop related question. I need to get some inputs from you regarding hadoop. I searched your blog too,But sadly i din find any contact info. If you could, please provide me your mail id. Or else I ll give my mail Id. I would be happy if i hear from you.. :)

Answer (score 0):

try using 0.20.X hadoop core package version to make use of org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.* classes